# declare Mat in OpenCV java

Tags: java, opencv

How can I create and assign a Mat with Java OpenCV? The C++ version from [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) is

```
Mat C = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0);
```

What would be the equivalent in Java OpenCV?  It seems that the documentation for Java OpenCV is lacking. What does exist often contains C++ code that doesn't work in Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. The documentation is minimal or non existing. An equivalent would be

```
Mat img = new Mat( 3, 3, CvType.CV_64FC1 );
int row = 0, col = 0;
img.put(row ,col, 0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0 );
```

In opencv java doc([1](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#put(int,%20int,%20double...))) for `Mat` class, see the overloaded `put` method

```
public int put(int row, int col, double... data )
public int put(int row, int col, float[] data )
public int put(int row, int col, int[] data )
public int put(int row, int col, short[] data )
public int put(int row, int col, byte[] data )
```

We can see that for data types other than `double`, the last parameter is an array and not variable argument type. So if choosing to create `Mat` of different type, we will need to use arrays as below

```
int row = 0, col = 0;
int data[] = {  0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0 };
//allocate Mat before calling put
Mat img = new Mat( 3, 3, CvType.CV_32S );
img.put( row, col, data );
```

Comment: Hi @Kiran, would you mind help to take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226304/how-to-declare-a-small-image-for-test-in-opencv-android

Comment: Why are the row and col values zero? What does it mean?