# How to declare a small image for test in openCV Android?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

The document is minimal or non existing, I've read [OpenCV's official doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html) and [declare Mat in OpenCV java from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338864/declare-mat-in-opencv-java)

I've did some research of image processing algorithm use Python Jupyter notebook, at this moment I want to verify it in Android python.

For the Python part:

```
from numpy import asarray

dimg = cv2.imread('story/IMG_0371.PNG')
dimg_small = dimg[571:572, 401:402]
dimg_small_gamma = adjust_gamma(dimg_small)
data = asarray(dimg_small)
data_gamma = asarray(dimg_small_gamma)

# print data
array([[[52, 45, 44]]], dtype=uint8)
# print data_gamma
array([[[115, 107, 105]]], dtype=uint8)
```

The image of `dimg_small` would like:

[image]

Meanwhile the image of `dimg_small_gamma` would like:

[image]

So far, I want to create an image with the same data `[52, 45, 44]` and `115, 107, 105` in Android to verify my algorithm, both Java or Kotlin would be fine.

```
private fun genTestMat(): Mat { //upper one
    val img =  Mat( 3, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    img.put(3, 1,52.0, 45.0, 44.0)
    return img
}

private fun genTestMat2(): Mat { //under one
    val img =  Mat( 3, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    img.put(3, 1,115.0, 107.0, 105.0)
    return img
}

private fun opencvMatToBitmap(mat: Mat): Bitmap {
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.width(), mat.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bitmap)
    return bitmap
}

...

val testImg = opencvMatToBitmap(genTestMat())
val testImg2 = opencvMatToBitmap(genTestMat2())

image_under.setImageBitmap(testImg2)
image_upper.setImageBitmap(testImg)
```

With the image show in my Android device:
[image]

I was wondering how to make the Android show the same image as is in Python Jupyter notebook?

Updated:

Tried to `Mat.put` using array as follows:

```
private fun genTestMat(): Mat { //upper one
    val img =  Mat( 3, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    val data = floatArrayOf(52f, 45f, 44f)
    img.put(1,1, data)
    return img
}
```

Unfortunately it crashed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 16
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.put(Mat.java:801)
        at com.example.cap2hist.MainActivity.genTestMat(MainActivity.kt:131)
```

Comment: Can you attach the TraceBack or atleast exception message ?

Comment: @ZdaR Awesome thanks, got the error that `CvType` should be ` CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4` , changed the code to `val img =  Mat( 3, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3)` now it doesn't crash. Not sure which type of `CvType` is appropriate. I will do some research on it.

Answer (score 0):

After chat with folks in openCV [forum](https://answers.opencv.org/question/229248/how-to-declare-a-small-image-for-test-in-opencv-android/), got the answer.

```
private fun genTestMat(): Mat {
    val inputMat = Mat( 1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    val rgbMat = Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputMat, rgbMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 3)
    rgbMat.setTo(Scalar(52.0, 45.0, 44.0))
    return rgbMat
}
```